# Django in template timeuntil if statement

Tags: django, if-statement

i would like to have kind of a todo list, where i have a model called "projekt" and i want colorize the html output depending on the timeuntil tag (if less then 7 days it should have the bootstrap class "danger" and if its more then 7 days it should have the class "success"

here my models.py:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    beginning_project = models.DateField()
    beginning_project_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    deadline = models.DateField()
    deadline_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    beschreibung = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nam
```

here's my views.py:

```
def Home(request):
    proj = Project.objects.filter(active=True)
    context = {
    'proj':proj
    }
    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

and as last my template:

home.html:

```
{% for proj in proj %}
        <div class="row mx-auto text-center">
            <div class="col-12 projcard">
                <a href="{% url 'apps:Project' %}">
                    <p class="display-4 mx-auto">
                        {{ proj.name }}x
                    </p>
       {% if proj.beginning_project|timeuntil > 7 %}
                    <button class="btn btn-success">                    
                        <u>
                            starts in {{ proj.beginning_project|timeuntil }} 
                        </u>
                    </button>
       {% else %}
                    <button class="btn btn-danger">                    
                        <u>
                            starts in {{ proj.beginning_project|timeuntil }} 
                        </u>
                    </button>
       {% endif %}
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your **views.py** you can do:

```
from datetime import datetime

def Home(request):
    proj = Project.objects.filter(active=True)
    today = int(datetime.now().strftime("%d"))

    for p in proj:
        if p.beginning_project.day - today > 7:
             p.danger_mode = False
        else:
             p.danger_mode = True
```

and then in your **home.html**:

```
{% for proj in proj %}
    <div class="row mx-auto text-center">
        <div class="col-12 projcard">
           <a href="{% url 'apps:Project' %}">
               <p class="display-4 mx-auto">
                   {{ proj.name }}x
               </p>
               <button class="btn btn-{% if proj.danger_mode %}danger{% else %}success{% endif %}">                    
                   <u>
                       starts in {{ proj.beginning_project }} 
                   </u>
               </button>
           </a>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your hint. But the beginning_project is a DateField not a DateTimeField so .hour doesn't work. If i replace .hour with .day then an error in the template shows up "Could not parse the remainder: '>7' from 'proj.beginning_project>7'"

Comment: hello again, perfect, thanks! can you explain it a little bit? :D

Comment: try to read and understand the code, it is the best way to permanently keep what you've learned  in your mind ;) goodluck

Comment: hello again,yeah sure, thanks for that. how would i do this in a class-based view (detailview) ?